# Loading Google Javascript libraries into Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, loading, libraries

I am trying to make my Meteor App work. It needs to use some of the Google libraries. In particular, these two:

https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=loadGooglePlatformLib
https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js

My understanding is that these aren't available as a Meteor package yet. I tried the following approaches:

(1) Putting these in the head section of a layout. However, every time the layout is rendered (which is for all of my templates), these files are reloaded causing latency.

(2) I tried a dynamic load via $.getscript (of Jquery). However, despite using overridable cache options that this can be wrapped with, there's a reload of these files here as well.

Can someone advise what may be the best way to achieve loading of these library files without avoiding the reloads I experience each time?

Thanks
np

Answer (score 0):

What I do is put my head section in a separate file, such as `client/main.html`, which only contains the `head` for my app:

```
<head>
  <script src="//apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
</head>
```

To my knowledge, this method doesn't reload files at every template rendering, only when refreshing the page.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried this, but I still get a reload of the files for every template rendering. I was wondering if these libraries need to be downloaded, perhaps wrapped in a package and then be used as a potential solution?